# YII Criteria 'With' relation issue

Tags: activerecord, yii, criteria

```
WHEN IAM TRYING TO GET invoice created user and grn created user i am getting this error...
```

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'user'.
>   The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`grn ......

```
 $criteria->with = array(
                "invoice.user" => array('select' => 'display_name'),
                "grn.user" => array(
                    'select' => 'display_name',
                ),


    );
```

please help me to solve this...

Comment: You need to give one of those two relations a different alias. See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219716/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-yii-with-cgridview-when-relation-is-a).

Comment: ya i tried that...it also gives me an error...can you give give me a code for this

Answer (score 2):

You should specify an alias for either (or both) of the relationships like this:

```
$criteria->with = array(
  "invoice.user" => array(
    'alias' => 'invoiceUser', 
    'select' => 'display_name'
  ),
  "grn.user" => array(
    'alias' => 'grnUser',
    'select' => 'display_name',
  ),
);
```